# Ubuntu 12.10 hangs on checking battery state

Tags: intel-graphics, boot-failure

I have a Thinkpad X230. After a boot it hangs with checking battery state [OK]. A second boot is most times successful.

What I have seen in other posts doesn't fit to my problem, because

- My graphics card is Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics controller (not nvidia)
- It happens not always
- I have a fresh installed 12.10 with the latest updates (no upgrade)

Does anyone experience the same issues or has a solution?

Comment: The other answer, which has a link to [this site](http://dbastreet.com/blog/?p=972) could only a **temporary** solution Is there a real solution?
My Laptop with INTEL HD4000 graphics hang up with this error message every time I boot it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least one other person had the same problem and found a solution:

http://dbastreet.com/blog/?p=972

Answer (score 0):

If `Xorg.1.log` near the end has these lines:

```
[     3.404] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"    
[     3.404] (II) Unloading intel
[     3.404] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[     3.404] 
Fatal server error:
[     3.404] no screens found
```

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261963/xorg-no-screens-found-on-startup-in-12-04-2-lts) worked for me. It seems lightdm is way too light. You gotta slow this baby down by adding a sleep step to it.