# Xorg: no screens found on startup in 12.04.2 LTS

Tags: xorg, lightdm

I have an Intel IvyBridge video card.  This morning, my 12.04.02 LTS treated me to an Xorg server crash.

- Trying an older kernel worked once, but lead to the same error during reboot.  The problem does not appear to be related to the kernel.
- Restarting lightdm did get me to a GUI login screen:

  ```
  sudo service lightdm stop

  sudo service lightdm start
  ```

So now I'm able to do a little bit of diagnostics.  I did a diff of the Xorg logs between the first Xorg start (which crashed) and the second (which succeeded).  They look similar, until a certain point.

Good:

```
[   310.379] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
    i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
    E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
    965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
    4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
    Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
    Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
    Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server,
    Ivybridge Server (GT2)
[   310.379] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   310.379] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   310.379] (++) using VT number 7

[   310.380] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   310.380] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[   310.380] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   310.380] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   310.380] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   310.380] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   310.380] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   310.380]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[   310.380]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[   310.380] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[   310.380] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[   310.380] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:02.0
[   310.380] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[   310.380] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[   310.380] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[   310.380] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:02.0
[   310.380] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
```

Bad:

```
[     2.986] (II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
    i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
    E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
    965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
    4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale,
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT1), Sandybridge Desktop (GT2),
    Sandybridge Desktop (GT2+), Sandybridge Mobile (GT1),
    Sandybridge Mobile (GT2), Sandybridge Mobile (GT2+),
    Sandybridge Server, Ivybridge Mobile (GT1), Ivybridge Mobile (GT2),
    Ivybridge Desktop (GT1), Ivybridge Desktop (GT2), Ivybridge Server,
    Ivybridge Server (GT2)
[     2.986] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     2.986] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     2.986] (++) using VT number 7

[     2.987] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[     2.987] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[     2.987] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     2.987] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     2.987] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     2.987] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     2.987] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     2.987]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[     2.987]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[     2.987] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     3.151] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     3.287] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:02.0
[     3.287] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     3.287] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     3.287] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[     3.287] drmOpenByBusid: Interface 1.4 failed, trying 1.1
[     3.287] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports 
[     3.287] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card1
[     3.291] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.291] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card2
[     3.295] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.295] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card3
[     3.299] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.299] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card4
[     3.302] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.302] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card5
[     3.306] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.306] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card6
[     3.310] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.310] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card7
[     3.314] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.314] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card8
[     3.317] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.317] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card9
[     3.321] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.321] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card10
[     3.325] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.325] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card11
[     3.329] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.329] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card12
[     3.332] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.332] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card13
[     3.336] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.336] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card14
[     3.340] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.340] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card15
[     3.344] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns -1
[     3.344] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     3.344] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     3.404] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     3.404] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     3.404] drmGetBusid returned ''
[     3.404] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.
[     3.404] (EE) intel(0): Failed to become DRM master.
[     3.404] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     3.404] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     3.404] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[     3.404] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     3.404] (II) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop (GT1)
[     3.404] (--) intel(0): Chipset: "Ivybridge Desktop (GT1)"
[     3.404] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[     3.404] (II) Unloading intel
[     3.404] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[     3.404] 
Fatal server error:
[     3.404] no screens found
[     3.404]
```

More questions:

- Why is Xorg crashing at startup, and why is it able to start normally shortly after?
- Is this a bug?  If yes, I'll go file a report.

I can post the full logs if anybody is interested.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdrm/+bug/982889

There's a recommended workaround that worked for me:

```
A workaround is to add some sleep to /etc/init/lightdm.conf:

    sleep 10
    exec lightdm
```

BTW, 1 second was enough.

Comment: For meeven `sleep 0.5` is enough.